# Chain methods in Comparator.comparing of List in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following Objects

```
Class Trade{
   private Integer tradeId;
   private Event  eventId;
   private Integer tradeVersion;
}

Class Event{
  private Integer value;
}
```

1. For the above scenario I am trying to write something like `Comparator.comparing(Trade::getEventId().getValue())`
2. The above did not work
3. So for now I went with the usual lambda which is the following

   `someList.sort((Trade o1, Trade o2) -> o1.getEventId().getValue().compareTo(o2.getEventId().getValue()))`;

and it worked but curious to know if  #1 is possible?

4. Tried `Comparator.comparing(Trade::getEventId).thenComparing(Event::getValue)` but no joy.
5. Note that both of these classes are third party so I cannot alter them.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? a comparator for comparing `Trade`s by event value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's as easy as :

```
trades.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(x -> x.getEventId().getValue()));
```

Also notice that your version with `Comparator.comparing(Trade::getEventId).thenComparing(Event::getValue)` would semantically mean that you are *first* sorting by `eventId` then by `value` which looks like *not* what you want in the first place.

Comment: that's Brilliant. I was expecting something like the above but dint know about it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

Expression `Comparator.comparing(Trade::getEventId().getValue())` does not work, because this is invalid use of [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). With `::` operator you can refer to a single method, like `Trade::getEventId`. This is an equivalent for following lambda expression:

```
trade -> trade.getEventId()
```

Although you may try using following `Function<Trade, Integer>` represented as a following lambda expression:

```
(Function<Trade, Integer>) trade -> trade.getEventId().getValue()
```

Then your comparator could be defined as:

```
Comparator.comparing((Function<Trade, Integer>) trade -> trade.getEventId().getValue())
```

PS: casting to `Function<Trade, Integer>` can be avoided probably.